# Is there a way to get 20 or 30 km/ h speed limit roads and pedestrian only roads in OSMnx?

Tags: python, pandas, osmnx

I am trying to get the length (in m) AND surface (in square m) of all the walkable streets in a given city, for example Paris. From the documentation, I found this code to get the area of all walkable streets in square meters.

1. How can I know if "pedestrian only" streets are also included in this, apart from all pavements?
2. Also, is there a way to (separately from point 1.) get the zones/ streets where traffic is limited to 20 or 30 km/h?

Below is the code from the documentation which shows the surface and length of all walkable streets in Paris.

```
# Get the network graph for all streets and paths that pedestrians can use
G = ox.graph_from_place('Paris, France', network_type='walk')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_size=0, bgcolor='k')

# what sized area does our network cover in square meters?
G_proj = ox.project_graph(G)
nodes_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_proj, edges=False)
graph_area_m = nodes_proj.unary_union.convex_hull.area
graph_area_m

# show some basic stats about the network, "street_length_total" shows the length of all streets in the upper graph
ox.basic_stats(G_proj, area=graph_area_m, clean_intersects=True, circuity_dist='euclidean')
# street_length_total = sum of all edges in the undirected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I know if "pedestrian only" streets are also included in this, apart from all pavements?

I'd recommend familiarizing yourself with OSM's tagging, including how [pedestrian](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Pedestrian) related data are handled. Then you can easily inspect your graph, or convert it to a GeoDataFrame, or filter its nodes/edges by certain key:value tag pairs.

> Also, is there a way to (separately from point 1.) get the zones/ streets where traffic is limited to 20 or 30 km/h?

Yes. If [max speed](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) data exist in OSM for a given edge, you will find it in the edge's `maxspeed` attribute. You can filter by these attribute values.